# call a function using a JSON key and value in Python

Tags: python, websocket

I have run a websocket on Linux server to serve connected clients using a local network. my aim is to let the client to control some configurations.

A Web Application (compounded of PHP and HTML pages) play a roll as an interface,
when the home page is loaded it connects to the websocket using pure Javascript `var socket = new WebSocket("ws://SERVER_NAME:90/");`
an HTML element = input['text'] should send a JSON object that has a key and value like the following:

> var data = {}; 
>   data.key = input_value; 
>   socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

To be more clear: let's say that `key` is Greeting and `value` is Hello, So after JSON encoding, the string `{"Greeting":"Hello"}` will be sent to Server using web socket as mentioned, where the Server stores it in the buffer STDIN until the web socket script read it.

Python Script of Web Socket:

```
data = json.loads(stdin.readline());
for x in data:
    # the code that run the function Greeting
    pass
```

in one word:

> How to call function (Greeting) `which is the JSON-KEY` and pass the argument Hello as input parameter `which is JSON-VALUE`

My Web socket is OK, and I can receive the any string from any client,

> **NOTE:** I know that I can make a if/else to check the key if it's contained in the array then call the matched function, but it's useless because I have a lot of functions and For..Loop spent undesired time.

Sorry for this long question but it's so necessary to solve that problem.
I'm grateful for every help or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you'd pack the functions into a dict:

```
def greeting(value):
    print "Hello " + str(value)

FUNC_MAP = {
    'Greeting': greeting,
}
```

And then to call the function,

```
data = json.loads(stdin.readline());
for func_name, value in data.items():
    FUNC_MAP[func_name](value)
```

Of course, there might be some improvements that you could make here (e.g. error handling for functions that aren't present, etc).

Comment: Thank you so much ... that's what I need ... but please there is a tiny error which (can't concatenate integer value to "Hello") .. but all is done correctly

Comment: @AbdulkaderKhateeb -- I updated so the error should be gone if you update too.  (e.g. `'Hello ' + str(value)` rather than `'Hello ' + value` )

Comment: Mr, @mgilson, could you please tell me how to throw an exception when to call a function that is not in dictionary ... I totally new for Python ,.. thank a lot :)

Comment: @AbdulkaderKhateeb -- An exception will be thrown already (`KeyError`).  If you want to [handle that exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), then you need to decide what you want the code to do.

Comment: Mr. @mgilson, please I'm improving some thing in code so I need you o help me How I can pass more than one parameter to the function Greeting (e.g. the output should be "Hello " + id + ">>>>" + value

Comment: @AbdulkaderKhateeb -- You'd probably pass the parameters in the JSON as an array:  `{'function_name': ['param1', 'param2']}` And then you'd unpack the parameters in the call above:  `FUNC_MAP[func_name](*value)`.  Note that you'd probably want to _always_ pass an array of parameters, even if you have only one parameter in a particular function so that the unpacking would work correctly.

Comment: Thanks again. .. but what do u mean of astrike before (value) is it a pointer? And how can a pointer iterate fir unknown length of the array of parameter ?

Comment: It isn't a pointer.  It's parameter unpacking.  Have a look at the related section in the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)